# How to read both EPC and TID performing inventory (Zebra Xamarin RFID SDK)?

Tags: c#, rfid

I'm trying to get both EPC and TID while performing inventory, I'm using the Zebra Xamarin RFID SDK with RFD2000 reader.
For testing I'm using the c# demo source included with sdk.
So I enable

```
rfidReader.Events.SetAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(true);
```

and add an operation to the tagaccess sequence.

```
TagAccess tagAccess = new TagAccess();
TagAccess.Sequence Sequence = new TagAccess.Sequence(tagAccess, tagAccess);
TagAccess.Sequence.Operation op = new TagAccess.Sequence.Operation(Sequence);

op.AccessOperationCode = ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.AccessOperationRead;
op.ReadAccessParams.MemoryBank = MEMORY_BANK.MemoryBankTid;
rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.Add(op);
```

Before calling Inventory.Perform() I call

```
rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.PerformSequence();
```

and in the first second I can read in

```
aryTags[index].MemoryBankData
```

the TID value.

I just receive 2-3 EPC+TID tags while I've got several tags.
I receice an "Empty access sequence" and tried to "refill" the sequence without success.

Any advise or doc on how to resolve?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not enough rfid power set up? TID reading needs more power then EPC inventory reading.
Or you can maybe first inventory all tags in range and then go trough all epcs and read tid one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late for this answer but I had same problem a few weeks ago and I would like to share my solution.

I started from ZebraRFIDXamarinDemo included in SDK.

In ReaderModel.cs, in `ConfigureReader()`, I left

```
rfidReader.Events.SetAttachTagDataWithReadEvent(false);
```

because in SDK 2.0.1.116 the `EventReadNotify()` event is no more handled using `RfidReadEvents` argument

```
TagData tag = e.getReadEventData().tagData;
```

but using

```
TagData[] myTags = rfidReader.Actions.GetReadTags(100);
```

which returns `TagData`

I tried using operation sequence approach like you, but instead of creating a new `TagAccess` I used the one already created for `rfidReader.Actions`, and then I call

```
rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.PerformSequence();
```

**INSTEAD OF** calling

```
rfidReader.Actions.Inventory.Perform();
```

so my `PerformInventory()` in ReaderModel.cs became:

```
internal bool PerformInventory()
{
    try
    {

        rfidReader.ReinitTransport();

        TagAccess tagAccess = rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess;
        TagAccess.Sequence Sequence = new TagAccess.Sequence(tagAccess, tagAccess);
        TagAccess.Sequence.Operation op = new TagAccess.Sequence.Operation(Sequence);
        op.AccessOperationCode = ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.AccessOperationRead;
        op.ReadAccessParams.MemoryBank = MEMORY_BANK.MemoryBankTid;
        rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.DeleteAll();
        rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.Add(op);

        //rfidReader.Actions.Inventory.Perform();
        rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.PerformSequence();

        return true;
    }
    catch (InvalidUsageException e)
    {
        e.PrintStackTrace();
    }
    catch (OperationFailureException e)
    {
        e.PrintStackTrace();
        ShowAlert(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and finally `StopInventory()` call became:

```
    internal void StopInventory()
    {
        try
        {
            //rfidReader.Actions.Inventory.Stop();
            rfidReader.Actions.TagAccess.OperationSequence.StopSequence();
        }
        catch (InvalidUsageException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
        }
        catch (OperationFailureException e)
        {
            e.PrintStackTrace();
            ShowAlert(e);
        }
    }
```

This worked for me, I hope it could help someone else.